# Why is the shopkeeper so rude?

Tags: analysis, plot-explanation, downton-abbey

In downton abbey when bates goes to the limp corrector, why is the shop keeper so rude to him saying "as I make it and advertise it will I say no?" 
Is it because there was no customer service back in the day or it was English culture working class attitude. 
I know England is still not big on customer service as compared to American high streets. Just wanna know if it's a old cultural thing

Comment: Only an American would call that shopkeeper rude.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't get the correct quote; [according to the wikia](http://downtonabbey.wikia.com/wiki/Salesman_%28Limp_Corrector%29) it is:

> When Bates asks if it works, he flippantly replies "Well, as I make it
>   and I advertise it, is it likely I'd say no?"

The line is particularly relevant [in context](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Downton_Abbey#Episode_3):

> **Mr. Bates:** I saw this advertisement for a limp corrector. What does it do exactly?
>
> **Salesman:** It corrects limps.
>
> **Mr. Bates:** Does it work?
>
> **Salesman:** Well, as I make it and I advertise it, is it likely I'd say no?

Whilst that answer may be regarded as rude, I wouldn't be offended by it (if I had been Bates) and would shrug it off as a case of "I had to ask a stupid question, didn't I", especially since it was the second "stupid" question in a row. Moreover, the shopkeeper can afford to be rude because it's not like Bates has got an alternative.